# how to get first page content of docx in php

Tags: php, file

i want to get docx file fist page text only, suppose business.docx file has 5 pages, now i want to show only first page content and hide rest of the 4 pages text.
following is the code that read docx file.

```
function read_file_docx($filename)
{
    $striped_content = '';
    $content = '';

    if(!$filename || !file_exists($filename)) return false;

    $zip = zip_open($filename);

    if (!$zip || is_numeric($zip)) return false;


    while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip)) {

        if (zip_entry_open($zip, $zip_entry) == FALSE) continue;

        if (zip_entry_name($zip_entry) != "word/document.xml") continue;

        $content .= zip_entry_read($zip_entry, zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry));

        zip_entry_close($zip_entry);
    }// end while

    zip_close($zip);

    //echo $content;
    //echo "<hr>";
    //file_put_contents('1.xml', $content);     

    $content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc>', " ", $content);
    $content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p>', "\r\n", $content);
    $striped_content = strip_tags($content);

    return $striped_content;
}
```

i also want ms word text formatting like bold, italic, bullet, etc... i have google but cant get code which give me option to show docx first page content.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to look into below php library

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord

you can find samples https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/tree/master/samples

Comment: this is not what i want, i will upload docx file from computer and want to read that file. i have read docx file as i mention function above but now i want to show only docx first page and docx file formatting.

Comment: If you want to parse docx xml by yourself, you should need to look on Open XML format. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML you can find additional resources on MSDN. You should look into that and find how they save content for pages and how to extract 1st page.

Comment: Not a good package, it has limitations
It cant loop through pages,
Documentation is not good

But can be use for replacing data in the docs or creating a docs
It only has minimal functionality

Comment: @Forbidden Are you looking forward to create screenshot of each page of the doc?

Comment: Tried to get the page, or at least per page of the doc, but sadly no,
Also there are no documentation on how to get content from certain page.